# Weblogic, Filebeat Logstash : How to handle multilines

Tags: logging, weblogic, logstash

I'm trying to integrate the ELK stack in my JAVA application. 
I'm deploying my application to Weblogic and I'm using **Filebeat** to prospect the log files.

I'm trying to use a grok filter to collect some informations about my logs.
The logs are multilines as you see and I did succeed to collect each line separately by using this pattern in **pipeline.conf** :

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
}
```

I can't collect every block of log using the **multilines** (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) attribute
Here are my logs :

```
Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816081> 
================New Request: [GET /capella/login HTTP/1.1] =================
Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816081> INFO: SSL is not configured
Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816081> Using Uri /capella/login
Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816081> After trimming path: '/capella/login'
Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816082> 
================New Request: [GET /capella/login HTTP/1.1] =================
Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816082> INFO: SSL is not configured
Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816082> Using Uri /capella/login
```

Could someone give me a hand or an idea to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem, and will come in multiple steps.

#### Step 1: Multiline your inputs

This will cram all the log-lines for a single event into a single... event.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/app/pipeline.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "\<\d+\>$"
      negate  => true
      what    => previous
    }
  }
}
```

This will set every line following the `<number>` line as belonging to the 'number' line. When a new 'number' line is encountered, it will begin a new event. This will yield an event with:

```
message => "Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816081>\n================New Request: [GET /capella/login HTTP/1.1] =================\nFri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816081> INFO: SSL is not configured\nFri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816081> Using Uri /capella/login\nFri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816081> After trimming path: '/capella/login'\nFri May 19 10:13:28 2017 <519214951816082>"
```

All of your data is now in one event.

#### Step 2: Process those events.

This can get *rather* complicated. If you can trust the order in which the items on the lines following the '==' line arrive, you can construct a gnarly grok statement to capture it all. I'm afraid you'll have to build your grok-statement carefully. Here is an incomplete example:

```
^%{DATA:date} <%{NUMBER:transaction_id}>%{DATA}New Request: \[%{WORD:verb} %{DATA:path} HTTP/1.1]%{DATA}<%{NUMBER}> %{WORD:log_level}: %{DATA:log_message}\\n
```

This will populate the following fields:

```
date: "Fri May 19 10:13:28 2017"
transaction_id: "519214951816081"
verb: GET
path:  "/capella/login"
log_level: INFO
log_message: "SSL is not configured"
```

Figuring out the rest of the grok config is up to you. I hope I've demonstrated the method. http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ will be very handy in constructing your string.

Comment: I would suggest to use `Filebeat` here to handle multi-line events:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html   and then forward events to `Logstash`.  Unless `multiline codec` can mix events from multiple sources.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually took a different approach.
I recently run into that situation and I've decided to take a different approach.
I Have decided to go with Logstash json_event pattern for log4j(https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout).
This allowed me to have a lot of data extracted and parsed the good way.